# Implementing dynamic field adjustment in an INPUT form using Spring Boot and MySQL

Tags: java, html, mysql, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm currently working on a project where I need to implement a functionality that allows users to dynamically adjust the fields in an INPUT form. The configuration for these fields is stored in a MySQL database table called "additionalFields." This table has columns for "name," "type," and "defaultValue."

For this project, I have chosen to use the Spring Boot framework. My approach involved creating a class that holds a list of objects. I intended to create an object for each record in the MySQL table and add it to the list. However, I encountered an issue when trying to access the name associated with each object, which prevented the desired functionality. It's important to note that, for now, my goal is only to visualize the HTML form, and I'm not concerned with storing the records in the database.

To address this issue, I came up with an idea to create a custom class called "AdditionalField." This class would have two fields: "name" (for the field name) and "value" (for the field's type and value). In my main class, I would have a collection of type "AdditionalField." During the rendering process, I could access the fields by calling "hiring.getFields()" and retrieve the associated name and type using dot notation. This approach eliminates the problem where I cannot access the name of each object.

I would greatly appreciate any tips, guidance, or relevant links on how to implement this functionality effectively using Spring Boot and MySQL.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I intended to create an object for each record in the MySQL table and add it to the list. However, I encountered an issue when trying to access the name associated with each object, which prevented the desired functionality.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.